# What is the probability that a random vector $v_1$'s projection on the line joining $v_2$ and $v_3$ lies between $v_2$ and $v_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Consider three random vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ each of dimension $N$ whose coordinates are bounded between $[-1,1]$, what is the probability that the projection of $v_1$ on the line joining $v_2$ and $v_3$ will lie between $v_2$ and $v_3$?

Edit:

Lies between means, projection ($v_1$) on $v_2$ and $v_3$ lies on the line of $v_2$ and $v_3$ and also between $v_2$ and $v_3$. Projection can also be outside $v_2$ and $v_3$, like in the case of an obtuse triangle.

Comment: What have you tried? And If I may, what is the source of the problem?

Comment: Apart from writing the equation for the projection, I've got no ideas on how to proceed further. It was posed to me by a friend.

Comment: What does "lie between" mean?

Comment: I've added what lies between means in the edit.

Comment: When $N=1$, the answer is $\frac13$ by symmetry. In general, conditioning on $v_2$ and $v_3$, one is looking for the probability that a linear function of the coordinates of $v_1$ lies in the interval $[0,1]$, which is the volume of a particular polytope formed by parallel planes. I don't see an easy way to evaluate that (nor then to average over $v_2$ and $v_3$) but it's a concrete problem. Try the $N=2$ case?

Comment: For $N = 2$ the probability would be ratio between, area between the parallel lines through $v_2$ and $v_3$ and total area of the valid region. I want to see what happens when $N$ increases. If there's any analytical solution to this.